# AngularJS GET request with 2 parameters using $http

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I want to get an addition(operation a+b = c) using JavaRest, method GET with 2 double parameters and AngularJS to get the generated resource, but I still blocked.

here is the code:

```
//CalculatorResource.java
@Path("calco")
public class CalculeteResource {

double result;

@GET
@Path("/addition/{a}/{b}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getAddition(@PathParam("a") double a, @PathParam("b") double b) {

    Calculete calco = new Calculete();
    calco.setA(a);
    calco.setB(b);
    result = calco.getA() + calco.getB();
    calco.setC(result);
    return Response.ok(calco).build();
}
```

//succesfull test on server using http:

http://localhost:8380/dadem-calculator/rest/calco/addition/5/5

and generated object is, a+b=c (5+5=10)

```
{"a":5.0,"b":5.0,"c":10.0}
```

and here the PROBLEM: the AngularJS Controller with GET + 2 Params:

```
var app = angular.module("CalculatorManagement", []);

//Controller
app.controller("CalculatorController", function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.result;
    $scope.operation={
            a : 0,
            b : 0,
            c : 0
        };


    //HTTP GET- get all users collection
    function _refreshUserData() {
        $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : 'http://localhost:8380/dadem-calculator/rest/calco/addition/' + operation.a + '/' + operation.b
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.result = response.data;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log(response.statusText);
        });
    };

});
```

html with ng-model:

```
        <td><input type="number" ng-model="operation.a"></td>


        <td><input type="number" ng-model="operation.b"></td> 

        <td> {{ result.c }} </td>

    </tr>
```

Comment: There is a typo in your http get: + operation.a '/' , you are missing a '+'. It should be + operation.a + '/'

Comment: are you getting any error in console?

Comment: What are you seeing in the network tab of your Developer Tools?

Comment: Is there any reason to have operation.c property of the object? You are not setting it anyway, at least no in here and you are storing the result else where.

Comment: @GustavoGabriel and others users, I have try all your propositions but it's not work

Comment: 'localhost:8380/dadem-calculator/rest/calco/addition/'; + operation.a + '/' operation.b

Comment: @MichalTakáč , operation.c should be the result of operation.a + operation.b

Comment: @Manu Yes, but in the same time you are not assigning result to it anywhere where I can see, thats why i had this question.

Answer (score 0):

Where u called this function?
 You have to pass this object into that function or simple write $scope.operation.a/b

Comment: function _refreshUserData($scope.operation.a/b) {
   $http({
    method : 'GET',
    url : 'http://localhost:8380/dadem-calculator/rest/calco/addition/' + operation.a + '/' operation.b
   }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.result = response.data;
   }, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log(response.statusText);
   });
  };
  
  $scope.operation.a = result.a;
  $scope.operation.b = result.b;
  $scope.operation.c = result.c;

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module("CalculatorManagement", []);
app.controller("CalculatorController", function($scope, $http) {

$scope.result;
$scope.operation={
        a : 0,
        b : 0,
        c : 0
    };


//HTTP GET- get all users collection
function _refreshUserData() {
    $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : 'http://localhost:8380/dadem-calculator/rest/calco/addition/' + $scope.operation.a + '/' + $scope.operation.b
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.result = response.data;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response.statusText);
    });
};
});
```